# Function / ternary operator in BindinUtils.bindProperty method

Tags: data-binding, binding, flex4, ternary-operator

I've got a label in my mxml like this;

```
   <s:Label id="lblChange" text="{_symbol.change>0 ?  '+' + _symbol.change:_symbol.change}" />
```

This works perfectly fine, but I need to replace the binding via curly brackets with BindingUitls, something like this;

```
_changeWatcher = BindingUtils.bindProperty(lblChange, "text", _symbol, "change");
```

Again, works fine, but without the if/else case. So I though I could just write a function to do that;

```
private function checkValue(val:Number):String {
    if (val > 0)
        return "+"+val;
    else
        return val as String;
}
```

and use it as a property in the bindProperty call instead of change;

```
.bindProperty(lblChange, "text", _symbol, checkValue(_symbol.change));
```

However, bindProperty seems to accept nothing but strings here. So what way is there to get around this 'feature'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
BindingUtils.bindSetter(checkValue, _symbol, "change");

private function checkValue(object:Object):void {
    var val:Number = object as Number;
    if (val > 0)
        lblChange.text = "+"+val.toString();
    else
        lblChange.text = val.toString();
}
```